# What is the correct selector for direct children when binding delegated events with jQuery .on()

Tags: javascript, event-handling, jquery

I am trying to bind an event to direct children of the container element with jQuery `.on()`. It seems that I can't start the selector with ">", so what is the correct way to form the selector string here?

```
<div id="#parent">
  <div id="#unknown_id"><!-- Event should be run if triggered here -->
     <div id="#another_unknown_id"><!-- But not here --></div>
  </div>
  <div id="#one_more_unknown_id"><!-- Event should be run if triggered here -->
     <div>...</div>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript>">
$('#parent').on('custom_event', 'div', function(e) {
    alert('Now triggerer custom_event on #unknown_id');
});

$('#unknown_id').trigger('custom_event'); // This should trigger an alert
$('#one_more_unknown_id').trigger('custom_event'); // ... this should too
$('#another_unknown_id').trigger('custom_event'); // This should NOT do anything
</script>
```

I could do

```
$('#parent > div').on('custom_event', function(e) { });
```

but unfortunately the contents of `#parent` is loaded asynchronously with AJAX and t[he documentation of `.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) says the elements should exists when `.on()` is called (direct events).

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time.

---

Update after fiddling. It seems that **`>` does not work with jQuery 1.7.2**, but 1.8 onwards it works. See the accepted answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14480482/769144

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't see the problem starting the selector with `>` to select direct descendants.

```
$('#parent').on('custom_event', '> div', function(e) {
    alert('Now triggerer custom_event on ' + $(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/wY89L/1/

However, your third test

```
$('#another_unknown_id').trigger('custom_event'); // This should NOT do anything
```

*Does* do something - it triggers the event on `unknown_id` as it's propagated up the DOM by default. The only way you could stop this is to handle the event on all `div` elements and, when you determine the event is not valid, stop propagation of the event. Something like:

```
$('#parent').on('custom_event', 'div', function(e) {
    if($(this).parent().attr('id') != 'parent'){
         e.stopPropagation();
        return;
    }
    alert('Now triggerer custom_event on ' + $(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/wY89L/3/

Comment: Thanks Jamiec for the answer, I was just editing the Fiddle to handle this event propagation - http://jsfiddle.net/wY89L/2/ . =)

However, it seems that my original problem was due jQuery 1.7.2. When testing on that, starting the selector with > did not work. From 1.8.* upwards everything works.

Comment: a wealth of useful information in this post, though i already knew it.